# How Prophets Reply and Help with Rashi

Tags: rashi, nevua-prophecy, melachim-kings-book-of, ezekiel--the-book

**In Ezekiel 37:3**

> Then He said to me; "Son of man, can these bones become alive?" And I answered, "*O Lord God, You [alone] know*."

Ezekiel replies by saying Hashem knows.

**In 2 Kings 20:14**, Rashi comments that Hezekiah’s response to Isaiah, alongside similar expressions by other figures in the Torah, included some level of “haughtiness.”

Rashi quotes the above mentioned verse in Ezekiel to demonstrate what would have been a proper response.

**My question is twofold:**

Surely Ezekiel knew (I believe), why did he reply the way he did?

And what is Rashi trying to demonstrate by comparing Hezekiah’s answer (of who these people are) to Ezekiel’s answer (of a yes-or-no question)?